# How do I find the date format ?

Tags: python, datetime

I am receiving a json that prints time data '2016-04-15T02:19:17+00:00' I I cant seem to figure out the format of this unicode string.

I need to find a difference in time between then and now. The first step in that is to convert the string to structured format and Iam not able to find the format

```
fmt='"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' 
#fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' 
print datetime.datetime.strptime(result_json['alert_time'], fmt)
```

I keep getting exception that it is not the same format

```
time data '2016-04-15T02:19:17+00:00' does not match format '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your format.  First, it has a double quote `"` in it.  Second, you need to include the `T` between the date and the time.  Third, the timezone offset is not standard.  Here is code that will work:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-04-15T02:19:17', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

If your `alert_time` is always in GMT, you can just trim the timezone off before calling `strptime`.

Comment: I keep getting : unconverted data remains: +00:00 . Is there a graceful way to get rid of the exception ?

Comment: @Victor: "trim the timezone off before calling `strptime`."

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Brent is the safer and faster option rather than having things going on under the hood. But the amount of times I've had `datetime` as a frustrating bottleneck not associated with the main problem I wanted to test out, I will also point out that `dateparser` [here](http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  has not yet been wrong for me and will take a huge range of inputs.

```
import dateparser
import datetime

date = '2016-04-15T02:19:17+00:00'

date_parser_format = dateparser.parse(date)
datetime_format = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-04-15T02:19:17', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

print date_parser_format
print datetime_format
```